# Displaying wrong image in the list while the src of the image is different in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, image, model-view-controller

I have some ppt files in a list now when I click on a particular ppt then I am generating image of each slide and storing in a folder.Now I want to display all the images in a list.
Here is my html to display the images.

```html
 <div class="sideBySide">
        <div id="dvLeft" class="left" style="overflow: scroll; height: 400px; float: left">
                                  
            
        </div>
        <div class="right" >
            <ul class="target connected" style="float: left; width: 300px"></ul>
        </div>
       
    </div>
```

Here is my script

```js
  $(".lnk").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var vPath = $(this).attr("href");
                debugger;
                //$("#viewPlaceHolder").load("/home/generateImageList?strPath=" + $(this).attr("href"));
                //$(".left").html("/home/generateImageList?strPath=" + $(this).attr("href"));
                //$("#iPPT").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));

                //---------------
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { "strPath": vPath },
                    url: '@Url.Action("generateImageList", "home")',
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                        $('#dvLeft').empty();
                        $('#dvLeft').html(result);
                        //$('.left').html("<ul class='source connected'><li>Audi</li></ul>");
                        $(".source, .target").sortable({
                            connectWith: ".connected"
                        });
                    }
                });
                //---------------
            })
        });
```

Here is my action

```
public ActionResult generateImageList(string strPath)
    {
        try
        {

            // load a PowerPoint document
            PPTXDocument doc = new PPTXDocument(strPath);

            //Delete files
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Sajal\ResterEdgeApiTest\PPTSlider\Test\");

            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }

            // convert all PowerPoint document pages/slides to PNG files
            // page index will automatically append to the file name
            doc.ConvertToImages(ImageType.PNG, @"D:\Sajal\ResterEdgeApiTest\PPTSlider\Test\", "0");

            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Sajal\ResterEdgeApiTest\PPTSlider\Test\");
            List<FileInfo> files = dirInfo.GetFiles().OrderBy((f) => Int32.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name))).ToList();
            List<clsPPT> ppts = new List<clsPPT>();
            int i = 1;

            /****************************/
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<ul class='source connected' style='float: left'>");
            /****************************/

            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                clsPPT cp = new clsPPT();
                cp.strName = item.Name;

                string strPath1 = @"http://localhost:63714/Test/" + item.Name;
                //Uri myuri = new Uri(strPath1);
                cp.strPath = strPath1;//myuri;
                cp.rowNo = i;
                ppts.Add(cp);
                sb.Append("<li><p>" + i.ToString() + "</p><img id='" + i + "' src='" + strPath1 + "' height='200' width='300' alt='" + strPath + "' /></li>");
                i = i + 1;
            }
            sb.Append("</ul>");
            ViewBag.htmlDesig = sb.ToString();
            //return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_ppSlideList.cshtml", ppts);
            //return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_ppSlideListNew.cshtml", ppts);

            return Json(sb.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

When first time I am clicking on the ppt it's loading correct images but when I am clicking on the second ppt then image generation and html generation for the list is successful but it displaying the previous images which does not exist int folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add **`cache: false`** to your AJAX call as in:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    ...
});
```